# functional test in django cant find an element by id

Tags: python, django, tdd

I want to get the content of a table in a html file through `browser.find_element_by_id()`, but I always get the same error, even when I have tried different options. I don't know whether the error is in the html, the urls, the views or the tests files.

This is the error I get:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_multiple_users_can_start_lists_at_different_urls     (functional_tests.tests.NewVisitorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hugo/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraDjango/functional_tests/tests.py", line 71, in test_multiple_users_can_start_lists_at_different_urls
self.wait_for_row_in_list_table('1: Buy peacock feathers')
File "/home/hugo/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraDjango/functional_tests/tests.py", line 27, in wait_for_row_in_list_table
raise e
File "/home/hugo/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraDjango/functional_tests/tests.py", line 21, in wait_for_row_in_list_table
table=self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_list_table')
File "/home/hugo/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 341, in find_element_by_id
  return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
File "/home/hugo/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 855, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "/home/hugo/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/hugo/Code/AttractoraProject/AttractoraVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="id_list_table"]
```

This is the urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from Attractora import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home_page, name='home'),
    url(r'^Attractora/new$', views.new_list, name='new_list'),
    url(r'^Attractora/the-only-list-in-the-world/$', views.view_list, name='view_list'),
]
```

This is the views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from Attractora.models import Item

# Create your views here.
def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def view_list(request):
    items=Item.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'items':items})

def new_list(request):
    Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['item_text'])
    return redirect('/Attractora/the-only-list-in-the-world/')
```

This is the list.html file that contains the table

```
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>To-Do lists</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="/Attractora/list.htm">
            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a To-Do item"/>
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
       <table id="id_list_table">
       {% for item in items %}
           <tr><td>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ item.text }}</td></tr>
       {% endfor %}
       </table>
      </body>
</html>
```

And, finally, this is the tests.py file that raises the error:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import time

MAX_WAIT=100

class NewVisitorTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def wait_for_row_in_list_table(self, row_text):
        start_time=time.time()
        while True:
            try:
                table=self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_list_table')
                rows=table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
                self.assertIn(row_text, [row.text for row in rows])
                return
            except (AssertionError, WebDriverException) as e:
                if time.time() - start_time > MAX_WAIT:
                    raise e
                time.sleep(0.5)

    def test_can_start_a_list_and_retreive_it_later(self):
        # Edith has heard about a cool new online to-do app. She goes to   check out its homepage
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)

        # She notices the page title and header mention to-do list
        self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)
        header_text=self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').text
        self.assertIn('To-Do', header_text)

        # She is invited to enter a to-do item stright away
        inputbox=self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_new_item')
        self.assertEqual(inputbox.get_attribute('placeholder'), 'Enter a To-Do item')

        # She types "buy peacock feathers" into a text box (Edith's hobby is tying fly-fishing lures)
        inputbox.send_keys('Buy peacock feathers')

        # When she hits enter, the page updates, and now the page lists "1: Buy peacock feathers"
        # as an item in a to-do lists
        inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.wait_for_row_in_list_table('1: Buy peacock feathers')

        # There is still a text box inviting her to add another item. She enters "Use peacock feathers to make a fly"
        # (Edith is very methodical)
        inputbox=self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_new_item')
        inputbox.send_keys('Use peacock feather to make a fly')
        inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(1)

        # The page updates again, and now shows both items on her lists
        self.wait_for_row_in_list_table('1: Buy peacock feathers')
        self.wait_for_row_in_list_table('2: Use peacock feather to make a fly')

        # Satisfied, she goes back to sleep

    def test_multiple_users_can_start_lists_at_different_urls(self):
        # Edith starts a new to-do list
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        inputbox=self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_new_item')
        inputbox.send_keys('Buy peacock feathers')
        inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        self.wait_for_row_in_list_table('1: Buy peacock feathers')

        # She notices that her list has a unique URL
        edith_list_url=self.browser.current_url
        self.assertRegex(edith_list_url, '/Attractora/.+')

        # Now a new user, Francis, come along to the site

        ## We use a new browser session to make sure that no information of Edith's is coming through from cookies, etc.
        self.browser.quit()
        self.browser=webdriver.Firefox()

        # Francis visits the home page. There's no sign of Edith's Lists
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        page_text=self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
        self.assertNotIn('Buy peacock feathers', page_text)
        self.assertNotIn('make a fly', page_text)

        # Francis starts a new list by entering a new item. He is less interesting than Edith
        inputbox=self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_new_item')
        inputbox.send_keys('Buy milk')
        inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        self.wait_for_row_in_list_table('1: Buy milk')

        # Francis gets his own unique URL
        francis_list_url=self.browser.current_url
        self.assertRegex(francis_list_url, '/list/.+')
        self.assertNotEqual(francis_list_url, edith_list_url)

        # Again, there is no trace of Edith's list
        page_text=self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
        self.assertNotIn('Buy peacock feathers', page_text)
        self.assertIn('Buy milk', page_text)

        # Satisfied, they both go to sleep
```